# Why orthogonal polynomials lead to diagonal matrix $X^{T}X$ when estimating regression estimates?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares, regression-coefficients, polynomial

We believe that the response variable $Y$ can be modeled in a following way:

$$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \beta_2 x_i^2 + \beta_3 x_i^3 + \epsilon_i  $$

where $\epsilon_i$ is independently distributed with $N(0,\sigma^2)$.

We wish to fit the model:

$$E(Y_i) = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 \phi_1(x) + \gamma_2 \phi_2(x) + \gamma_3 \phi_3(x) $$

with explanatory variables of the form: $\phi_0(x)=1$, $\phi_1(x)=x$, $\phi_2(x)=x^2 - 4$ and $\phi_3(x)=x^3-7x$. It is pointed out that these are **orthogonal polynomials**. We then wish to estimate the regression coefficients of the cubic model with some data given.

Normally, I'd start with constructing matrix $X$, its transpose $X^T$ and then calculating $X^TX$ and then its inverse. However, according to me the matrix $X^TX$ would be:

$$
    X^TX = \begin{pmatrix}
    \sum \phi_0^2(x) & \sum \phi_0(x)\phi_1(x) & \sum \phi_0(x)\phi_2(x) & \sum \phi_0(x)\phi_3(x)\\
    \sum \phi_0(x)\phi_1(x) & \sum \phi_1^2(x) & \sum \phi_1(x)\phi_2(x) & \sum \phi_1(x)\phi_3(x)\\
    \sum \phi_0(x)\phi_2(x) & \sum \phi_1(x)\phi_2(x) & \sum \phi_2^2(x) & \sum \phi_2(x)\phi_3(x)\\
    \sum \phi_0(x)\phi_3(x) & \sum \phi_1(x)\phi_3(x) & \sum \phi_2(x)\phi_3(x) & \sum \phi_3^2(x)\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

But according to the solutions, we can see that it can be written as:

$$X^TX = diag\left(\sum \phi_0^2(x), \sum \phi_1^2(x), \sum \phi_2^2(x), \sum \phi_3^2(x) \right)$$

As the reasoning, it states that it is due to the fact that the explanatory variables are given as the orthogonal polynomials. And apparently it's quite obvious reason?

Is it true that the $X^TX$ is actually diagonal? And if so, how do the orthogonal polynomials make that happen?

Comment: This is what the "orthogonal" in "orthogonal polynomials" means.  What was pointed out to you is not well-defined: whether or not those expressions define orthogonal features depends on what you think their domain is.  I suspect you might therefore be conflating two closely related concepts.

Comment: In order to find a diagonal matrix, the polynomials must be *discrete* orthogonal polynomials, related to the design (i.e. the sequence of $x_i$s). A special case of interest is when $x_i :=i$ for $i = 1$ to $n$. This is the purpose of `contr.poly` in R; yet the function use the QR decomposition and not an explicit form of an othogonal family of polynomials.